# Column Ordering in SyBase Anywhere

Tags: sql, database, sybase-asa

I have a Sybase Anywhere database where in I have a table (say Table A). I need to check the ordering of columns within this table. Say if there are 3 columns in table A. 
`Col_1`, `Col_2` and `Col_3`

How can I check whether `Col_2` comes between `Col_1` and `Col_3`? Basically checking the ordering of columns within a table (if there are more than 3 columns in the table).

Answer (score 0):

You should query the database's system tables that represent the database structure. In SQL Anywhere 8 (last version I know) the interesting tables are SYS.SYSTABLE and SYS.SYSCOLUMN.

This query returns all columns of a table sorted by "logical" order:

```
SELECT c.column_id, c.column_name
FROM   sys.systable AS t
       INNER JOIN
       sys.syscolumn AS c
       ON c.table_id = t.table_id
WHERE  t.table_name = 'TableA'
ORDER BY c.column_id;
```

You could query the column_id of *Col_2* and check if it is between the column_ids of *Col_1* and *Col_2*.